# Bootstrap grid positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm trying to make a bootstrap website but I don't really know how to customize the widths and position of these grids. I'm a bootstrap beginner. Could you please help me? It DOESN'T have to be accurate so bad but I need to keep the layout.

How it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlwxP.png

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top:200px;" class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
    </div>
          <!--THIS ONE IS FOR THE MIDDLE, CENTERED AD-->
          <div class="col-md-4 column">
          </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-2 column">
    </div>
          <!--THIS ONE IS FOR BUTTONS STICKED TO THE POST ON THE LEFT-->
          <div class="col-md-1 column">
          </div>
          <!--THIS ONE IS FOR THE POST AND BUTTONS STICKED ON THE BOTTOM-->
          <div class="col-md-4 column">
          </div>
          <!--THIS ONE IS FOR THE SIDEBAR-->
          <div class="col-md-3 column">
          </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 column">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Bootstrap 3.0 release

> col-vp-push-x = push the column to the right by x number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render -> position: relative, on a vp or larger view-port.

```
col-vp-pull-x = pull the column to the left by x number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render -> position: relative, on a vp or larger view-port.

vp = xs, sm, md, or lg

x = 1 thru 12
```

So the answer to your question is push/pull columns. For example, your ad row should be like this:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-2 col-sm-push-2 advertisement">
        your center column
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on. [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s92rxc6f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need specific columns with pixel-specific widths, you can't use the Bootstrap grid. The Bootstrap grid is broken into 12 equal sized columns. You can still use Bootstrap, just not the grid part. There is some [limited customization](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) that can be done with the grid system, but I don't think it can approach what you are trying to do. You'll need to use custom CSS to position the site how you want it.

If you just want something similar and don't care about exact widths, then you should follow the [grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). You are moving in the right direction but when you have [nested columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) you need to make sure you wrap in a row, which you don't have. You can also use the col-md-offset-* styles to shift columns so you don't have to "use" all 12 columns. For example for the main part of the site you might want the first column to be ".col-md-3 .col-md-offset-4" and the second ".col-md-3".